# Integral $\int\limits_0^1\frac{-2\ln(x)(1+x^2)^2-2(1-x^4)}{(1-x^2)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int\limits_0^1\frac{-2\ln(x)(1+x^2)^2-2(1-x^4)}{(1-x^2)^3}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Are there any easy methods to solve this integral? I tried to solve this by series, but I don't know how to complete. I hope the answer does not contain th $\operatorname{Li}$ function.

The last answer from WolframAlpha is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$.

Comment: Perhaps the less messier way to integrate this thing is with complex integrals...

Comment: @MarkViola In fact the integrand is bounded as $x \to 1$.

Comment: Expand in Taylor series about $x=1$, keeping terms to order $(x-1)^3$.  You should get $-2 \ln(x)(1+x^2)^3 = -8 (x-1) - 12 (x-1)^2 - \frac{32}{3} (x-1)^3 + \ldots$ while $-2(1-x^4) = 8 (x-1) + 12 (x-1)^2 + 8 (x-1)^3 + \ldots$.

Comment: You can check the [$\LaTeX$-$\texttt{MathJax}$ MSE-Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For which purpose do you need to evaluate such integral? Please improve formatting, add your attempts and notice that a dilogarithm is obviously involved, since $\frac{\pi^2}{8} = \frac{3}{4}\text{Li}_2(1)$ !

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be your integrand.

Maple gives the antiderivative as

$$ \frac{1}{2(x+1)}+\frac{1}{2(x-1)}-\frac{\text{dilog}(x+1)}{2} -\frac{\ln  \left( x \right) \ln  \left( 
x+1 \right)}{2} -{\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x \left( x+2 \right) 
}{2\; \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}}}-\frac{{\text {dilog}} \left( x \right)}{2} +{
\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x \left( x-2 \right) }{2\; \left( x-1
 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x}{2\;(x+1)}}-{
\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x}{2\;(x-1)}}
$$
where
$$ \text{dilog}(x) = \int_1^x \frac{\ln(t)}{1-t}\; dt $$

In fact, if $F_1(x)$ contains the terms without dilog, 
$$ F_1(x) = \frac{1}{2(x+1)}+\frac{1}{2(x-1)}-\frac{\ln  \left( x \right) \ln  \left( 
x+1 \right)}{2} -{\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x \left( x+2 \right) 
}{2\; \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}}} +{
\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x \left( x-2 \right) }{2\; \left( x-1
 \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x}{2\;(x+1)}}-{
\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) x}{2\;(x-1)}}$$

you can verify that

$$F_1'(x) - f(x) = - \frac{\ln(x)}{2(x-1)} - \frac{\ln(x+1)}{2x}$$

and $$\lim_{x \to 0} F_1(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} F_1(x) = 0$$

So your integral becomes

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)\; dx}{2(x-1)} + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+1)\; dx}{2x} $$

Using the change of variables $u=x+1$ in the second of these and combining the two, we find your integral is

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2 \frac{\ln(x)\; dx}{x-1} $$

which I think is fairly "well-known".

Comment: Thank's alot sir